# Phonegap 2.8.0 and Xcode 4.6.3 - Fail to install ad-hoc distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, adhoc

i read all the guides, but nothing solves my problem.

In Apple Developer Center i have:

- 1 dev cert
- 1 distr cert
- all device listed
- the correct app_id -> bundle ID (in xcode)
- 1 dev profile
- 1 distribution profile

On my iPad 2, when i launch the application for testing, all is ok (with dev profile)

When i made an archive for create an IPA to install with iTunes, fails

I create an Build Configuration called ad-hoc with Distr Profile chosen in "code signing"

...this is the console log:

```
Jun 17 00:18:33 SergioiPad lockdownd[45] <Notice>: 01542000
__copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/PurchaseTypes -> (null)

Jun 17 00:18:37 SergioiPad installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7f000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/***.ipa" requested by itunesstored

Jun 17 00:18:37 SergioiPad installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7f000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app it.***.***

Jun 17 00:18:37 SergioiPad mobile_assertion_agent[101] <Notice>: service_one_connection: Connection closed for client iTunes.

Jun 17 00:18:37 SergioiPad installd[54] <Error>: Jun 17 00:18:37  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]

Jun 17 00:18:38 SergioiPad installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7f000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.66cmMz/foo_extracted/Payload/***.app/***: 0xe8008017

Jun 17 00:18:38 SergioiPad installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7f000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.66cmMz/foo_extracted/Payload/***.app

Jun 17 00:18:38 SergioiPad itunesstored[73] <Error>: 0x19ce000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1

Jun 17 00:18:38 SergioiPad installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7f000 install_application: Could not preflight application install

Jun 17 00:18:38 SergioiPad installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7f000 handle_install: API failed
```

What's the problem ?